# is there a persistent key for calendar events

Tags: android, events, calendar

My app needs to associate info with calendar events.  To do so, it needs a persistent id for each event so that it can track an event when its time changes or detect when it has been deleted.

In addition, I'd like an id that is native to the calendar, not just unique on the particular device, so that it is useful if my app runs on another android device or even another platform.

I've looked at _ID and _SYNC_ID.  It appears both are only unique and persistent on a particular device but not across devices.   The key I want is the native event key, from the calendar it belongs to.  For example, for an Outlook event, I think I want outlook's key.

Is such a key available from the Calendar api?  If not, is there anyway to get the native key I'm looking for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As best I can tell, Event_ID is as persistent as you will get.  It is the PK, so unless PKs are reused after a row is deleted, it should be reliable.  The only exception is if the user clears the calendar database and resynchs.  In that case, I think, all the PKs will be brand new.

Here's some source code from CalendarDatabaseHelper.java showing that Event._ID is the PK:

```
   db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Events (" +
            "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
            ACCOUNT_NAME + " TEXT," +
            ACCOUNT_TYPE + " TEXT," +
            "_sync_id TEXT," +
            "_sync_version TEXT," +
            "_sync_time TEXT," +            // UTC
            "_sync_local_id INTEGER," +
            "_sync_dirty INTEGER," +
            "_sync_mark INTEGER," + // To filter out new rows
            "calendar_id INTEGER NOT NULL," +
            "htmlUri TEXT," +
            "title TEXT," +
            "eventLocation TEXT," +
            "description TEXT," +
            "eventStatus INTEGER," +
            "selfAttendeeStatus INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "commentsUri TEXT," +
            "dtstart INTEGER," +               // millis since epoch
            "dtend INTEGER," +                 // millis since epoch
            "eventTimezone TEXT," +         // timezone for event
            "duration TEXT," +
            "allDay INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "visibility INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "transparency INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "hasAlarm INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "hasExtendedProperties INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "rrule TEXT," +
            "rdate TEXT," +
            "exrule TEXT," +
            "exdate TEXT," +
            "originalEvent TEXT," +  // _sync_id of recurring event
            "originalInstanceTime INTEGER," +  // millis since epoch
            "originalAllDay INTEGER," +
            "lastDate INTEGER," +               // millis since epoch
            "hasAttendeeData INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "guestsCanModify INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "guestsCanInviteOthers INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1," +
            "guestsCanSeeGuests INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1," +
            "organizer STRING," +
            "deleted INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0," +
            "dtstart2 INTEGER," + //millis since epoch, allDay events in local timezone
            "dtend2 INTEGER," + //millis since epoch, allDay events in local timezone
            "eventTimezone2 TEXT," + //timezone for event with allDay events in local timezone
            "syncAdapterData TEXT" + //available for use by sync adapters
            ");");
```